# Multi filter by 2 columns and display some best results with Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have df for my work with 3 main columns: cid1, cid2, cid3, and more columns cid4, cid5, etc. cid1 and cid2 is int, another columns is float.

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 9.0  ┆ 6.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 9.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
| 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 1.0      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

Each combitations of cid1 and cid2 is a workset for analysis and for each workset I have some values cid3.

I can take df with only maximal values of cid3:

```
df = df.filter(pl.col("cid3") == pl.col("cid3").max().over(["cid1", "cid2"]))
```

And this display:

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 9.0  ┆ 6.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 9.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 1.0      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

But I can't catch how I can take two maximal values of cid3 for each workset for this result:

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6     │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 9.0  ┆ 6.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 9.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
| 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 1.0      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

Two maximal values of cid3 is for example, for my task I can take 10 maximal values, 5 minimal and so that. Help me please!

Comment: It's helpful if you also provide your example as code, so we can run it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.top_k()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.top_k.html#polars.Expr.top_k) to get the `k` largest (or smallest) values.

`.unique().top_k()` can be used if you need distinct values.

```
df.groupby("cid1", "cid2").agg(pl.col("cid3").top_k(2))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬────────────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3       │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ list[f64]  │
╞══════╪══════╪════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ [9.0, 2.0] │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ [8.0, 3.0] │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

This can be used inside `.filter` combined with `.is_in`

```
df.filter(
   pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").top_k(2))
     .over("cid1", "cid2")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 9.0  ┆ 6.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

<strike>`descending=True` to find the minimal values (`bottom_k`)</strike>

**Update:** `.bottom_k` [has been added](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7969) and will be in the next release.

```
df.filter(
   pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").bottom_k(2)
     .over("cid1", "cid2")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Dataframe used:

```
df = pl.read_csv(b"""

cid1,cid2,cid3,cid4,cid5,cid6
1,5,1.0,4.0,4.0,1.0
1,5,2.0,5.0,5.0,9.0
1,5,9.0,6.0,4.0,9.0
3,7,1.0,7.0,9.0,1.0
3,7,3.0,7.0,9.0,1.0
3,7,8.0,8.0,3.0,1.0

""")
```

Comment: it's a good solution. I also did the top_k but then I realized the top_k does not take negative values. I wonder if the performance is the same

Comment: @Luca Ah, do you mean `descending=True`? I think a `.unique()` is also needed beforehand in the case of the max value appearing multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! In result, I make df.filter(pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").top_k(2)).over(["cid1", "cid2"]))

Comment: @Jahspear I think you also need `.unique()` - if `1,5,9.0` existed twice in your example: `.top_k(2) = [9.0, 9.0]` whereas `.unique().top_k(2) = [9.0, 2.0]`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to take it with all maximal values and [9.0, 9.0] is the good result

Comment: @Jahspear Ah understood, I'll change the answer to explain that `.unique` is optional if you want distinct values.

Comment: But I don't know why `df.filter(pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").top_k(2, descending=True)).over(["cid1", "cid2"]))` do not work for finding minimal values..

Comment: @Jahspear I've added in an example of `descending=True` - is that not the output you expect?

Comment: When I add `descending=True` i have an error.. hmmm..

Comment: What error? Perhaps you're on an older version of polars? `reverse=True` was the old name (I think?)

Comment: @jqurious: good catch for the unique. and I didn't know top_k had a parameter for descending, good thing to know

Comment: `reverse=True` is real solution) Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more possibility in case you want to get maximum or minimum values

Getting 2 largest values

```
df.filter(
    pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").unique().sort(descending=True).head(2))
    .over(["cid1", "cid2"])
    )

# Result
shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 9.0  ┆ 6.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 8.0  ┆ 8.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Getting 2 smallest values

```
(df.filter(
    pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").unique().sort(descending=False).head(2))
    .over(["cid1", "cid2"])
    )

# Result

shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ cid6 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 4.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ 2.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 5.0  ┆ 9.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 1.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 7    ┆ 3.0  ┆ 7.0  ┆ 9.0  ┆ 1.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: It's strange, but this variant get me an error..

Comment: fixed it. it was missing unique().

Comment: Working variant: `df.filter(pl.col("cid3").is_in(pl.col("cid3").sort(reverse=False).head(2)).over(["cid1", "cid2"]))` for finding minimal values. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Jahspear, reverse was used in an older version of Polars. The keyword argument is current descending: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.sort.html#polars.Expr.sort

Glad it's working now!